# AVCaptureSession captures black/dark frames after changing preset

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm developing app which supports both *still image* and *video* capture with `AVFoundation`. Capturing them requires different `AVCaptureSession` presets. I check for `canSetSessionPreset()`, begin change with `beginConfiguration()`, set required preset with `sessionPreset` and end with `commitConfiguration()`.

I found if I'm capturing still image with `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` **immediately** after changing preset, it returns no errors, but the resulting image is black or very dark sometimes.

If I start capturing video with `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` **immediately** after changing preset, first several frames in a resulting file are also black or very dark at times.

Right after changing preset the screen flickers likely due to the camera adjusting the exposure. So it looks like immediately after changing preset camera start measuring exposure from very fast shutter speed, which results in black/dark frames.

Both problems goes away if I insert a 0.1 second delay between changing the preset and starting capture, but that's ugly and no one can guarantee it will work all the time on all devices.

Is there a clean solution to this problem?

Comment: did you get solution for it?

Comment: @UserDev I haven't found better solution other than 0.1 second delay

Comment: Instagram has same issue on its main camera (if we immediate switch video to photo mode and click photo) but on the story camera (also in facebook) its very smooth capture image and video both.   How they are maintaining it on story camera ? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

This is for future users...

It was happening for me when I was setting the `sessionPreset` as `high` and as soon as I was starting recording I was making changes to video output connection and setting focus which I then moved to while setting up camera and it worked!!!

Comment: could you please show the code/example you tried with?

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! It's unbelievable, but it works! With sessionPreset = .photo the black screen appears on reinitialization, but with .high it work!